# How to serialize a generic object

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, system.text.json

I'm sorry for the bad title but I really don't know how to put this any other way. The detailed problem is as follows:

I have a .NET API with Controllers. I have a controller that has a reference to a service of generic type Entity and that returns an `IEnumerable` of generic `Dto<>`'s like so:

```cs
public class SomeController {
private readonly Service<SomeEntity> _someService;

    //constructor
    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Dto<SomeEntity>>> AsyncGetSomeData() {
        return await _someService.AsyncGet();
    }

}
```

The Service interface looks like this; it's purpose is to call a repository for entities and convert the entities to dto's in a way that a different `Dto` could be used for a given `Entity`:

```cs
public interface Service<T> where T : Entity
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Dto<T>>?> AsyncGet();
}
```

The Entity interface looks like this (for now):

```cs
public interface Entity {}
```

The Dto interface looks like this:

```cs
public interface Dto<T> where T : Entity.Entity {}
```

Implementations of the Entity interface can look like this:

```cs
public record SomeEntity (Guid id) : Entity
```

Implementation of the Dto can look like this:

```cs
public record SomeDto(string Id) : Dto<SomeEntity>;
```

When I return the objects in the way the controller is set up now (as described), empty json objects are returned. This is because the json serializer is not able to figure out that `Dto<SomeEntity>` can be serialized as `SomeDto`. This is proven by the fact that changing the signature to return `IEnumerable<SomeDto>` and casting the items in `IEnumerable<Dto<SomeEntity>>` to `SomeDto` does in fact serialize the objects correctly.

My question is: is it possible to change a setting or map `Dto<SomeEntity>` to `SomeDto` or something else to avoid having to change signatures and casting?

I have tried finding examples of something like this (Google and StackOverflow), but as you can see the problem is quite complicated to encapsulate in one sentence (I am accepting title suggestions to improve this question). I hope someone can either point me to a duplicate question or give me an answer.

EDIT:
I am trying to use the `JsonDerivedTypeAttribute`. I have two entity types and corresponding dto's:

```cs
public sealed record CourseDto() : Dto<CourseEntity>

public sealed record CourseDefinitionDto() : Dto<CourseDefinitionEntity>
```

Then, I have defined the `JsonDerivedTypeAttribute` on the `Dto` interface:

```cs
[JsonDerivedType(derivedType: typeof(CourseDto), "a")]
[JsonDerivedType(derivedType: typeof(CourseDefinitionDto), "b")]
public interface Dto<T> where T : Entity.Entity;
```

No matter what I use in the typeDiscriminator parameter, I get the following error:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: Specified type 'Application.Data.Dto.CourseDto' is not a supported derived type for the polymorphic type 'Application.Data.Dto.Dto`1[Application.Data.Entity.CourseDefinitionEntity]'. Derived types must be assignable to the base type, must not be generic and cannot be abstact classes or interfaces unless 'JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FallBackToNearestAncestor' is specified."

Comment: All serializers are generic. The problem is that you want to pick one of the infinite possible types that derive from `Dto<SomeEntity>` without actually specifying it. Why are you trying to do this? This looks like an attempt to overgeneralize something that's actually pretty specific - `SomeDto`

Comment: There may be multiple types of dto for one entity. The one used depends on the environment it is run in. Therefore, the service needs to be able to return a generic `dto<SomeEntity>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using System.Text.Json you should have a look at [JsonDerivedTypeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonderivedtypeattribute?view=net-7.0) and [JsonConverterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute?view=net-7.0)

Here is a quick sample of what you could do with `JsonDerivedTypeAttribute`

```
public interface Entity { }

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(SomeDto), "#some")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(AnotherDto), "#another")]
public interface Dto { }

public interface Dto<T> : Dto where T : Entity { }

public class SomeEntity : Entity { }

public class AnotherEntity : Entity { }

public class SomeDto : Dto<SomeEntity> { }

public class AnotherDto : Dto<AnotherEntity> { }
```

A sample to use

```
Dto some = new SomeDto();
Dto another = new AnotherDto();

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
var someJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(some, options);
var anotherJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(another, options);

Console.WriteLine(someJson);
Console.WriteLine(anotherJson);

var someDto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dto>(someJson);
var anotherDto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dto>(anotherJson);

Console.WriteLine(someDto?.GetType().Name);
Console.WriteLine(anotherDto?.GetType().Name);
```

Output

```
{"$type":"#some"}
{"$type":"#another"}
SomeDto
AnotherDto
```

**EDIT**

Here is a hint to get your controller able to return `Dto` interface, not generic `Dto<T>` interface.
You can do this because `IEnumerable<T>` interface is covariant.

```
public interface Service<T> where T : Entity
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Dto<T>>?> GetAsync();
}
```

Your action signature becomes

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Dto>?> GetSomeDataAsync()
{
    return await _someService.GetAsync();
}
```

I've switched `Async` word in method's name, to be more compliant with C# naming convention.

Comment: The JsonDerivedType attribute seems to work. Need to upgrade to .NET 7 but that's okay. It's a shame there's no way to map these things in the program.cs file because now my Dto interface is going to be HUGE

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening but after adding more than one JsonDerivedTypeAttribute on the Dto interface, everything falls apart and I get an error about serialization. How can I just declare that the type to be serialized should always be the runtime type, which always inherits from the Dto interface?

Comment: You should post your updated code with converters and attributes used. I can't guess what's going wrong without that.

Comment: I've added a working sample with `JsonDerivedTypeAttribute` - Hope it helps

Comment: I can't seem to get this working.

Comment: I think you should have one interface `Dto` not generic that handles all `JsonDerivedType` attributes. Then, your action should return `Task<IEnumerable<Dto>>`.

Comment: Thanks again for your input. You are suggesting to remove the generic in Dto. How would this help the serializer in understanding which implementation to serialize to? Shouldn't the previously suggested solution work? It would be dificult to remove the generic from Dto since the Service uses the generic type in Dto to determine which dto factory should be used to build the Dto from the Entity.

Comment: You don't need to remove the generic `Dto<T>` interface or implementation. Just add a `Dto` non-generic inferface, that handles all types with `JsonDerivedTypeAttribute` decoration.

Comment: `Dto<T>` can't be decorated with `JsonDervivedTypeAttribute` as it is generic. I've made an edit to simplify the code. As you can see, only the action signature changes. You trick the serializer with a non-generic `Dto` interface.

Comment: Once you have your non-generic `Dto` interface, make `Dto<T>` interface inherit from it, see the code I've written : `public interface Dto<T> : Dto where T : Entity { }`

Answer (score 1):

My advice is you give it both classes:

```
public class MyClass<Tin,Tout>
```

Comment: For `Service` class I presume, having `Task<IEnumerable<Tout>?> AsyncGet();`  method signature ? This would work also and would suppress any generic serialization issue.

Comment: Exactly, that would then be the method signature

Comment: That might conflict with the following requirement though : "There may be multiple types of dto for one entity. The one used depends on the environment it is run in." I guess that somehow `_someService` variable is injected at runtime. It is not really clear.

Comment: Yeah, then somtimes you would have to do var x = MyClass<C,C1>() and other times var x = MyClass<C,C2>, but that would have to be configured one place or the other anyway.

Comment: But how would you deal with action `AsyncGetSomeData` signature then ? Knowing C1 or C2 only at runtime ?

Comment: Runtime would not work, but I don't read the question as something that require runtime polymorphism, (then virtual classes would be the solution), but that is not how I have read the question.

Comment: It's written in the comments. I may have misunderstood, however.

Comment: Comment says: "The one used depends on the environment". So for the code I suggest they would have to use different initializations based on the environment they are in.